# One page customer login and showcase details (Custom Extension) in magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.8

i'm trying to create a POS system which will show case the products, order, login details, shipping details and payment in a single page. I have extracted the products and created a cart in the same page and created a login/create account, shipping and payment blocks. I would like to create a customer in the login block without having to be redirected to another page. Im able to extract the details of the customer using the following code from the table.

```
$customerModel = Mage::getModel('customer/customer'); //get customer model

            $customerCollection = $customerModel->getCollection();
            $customers = array();
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($customerCollection as $customer)
            {
                $customer = $customerModel->load($customer->getId());
                $customers[$i]['name'] = $customer->getName();
                $customers[$i]['email'] = $customer->getEmail();
                $customers[$i]['password'] = $customer->getPassword();
                $i++;
            }   

            foreach($customers as $k => $v)
            {
                $html.= 'Customer name :'.$v['name']. 'Customer Email :'.$v['email'].'Password:'.$v['password'];
            }
```

How do I create a customer through code and how do I authenticate the user and extract all his/her details without redirecting to another page.

Comment: Since its a one page extension could you please let me know how i can call the PHP functions during button click and retain the same page without loosing the data in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wire up some a aJax to register the user.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setFirstname('Joe');
$customer->setLastname('Bro');
$customer->setEmail('joebro@yahoo.com');
$customer->setPassword('');
$customer->save();
return $customer->getId();
```

Just check out app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

You could also return the ID after saving the user and

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->loginById($customer->getId());
```